# iTunes 11 Import Into Apple Music

Tags: itunes, snow-leopard

I have a really old IMO Snow Leopard intel iMac that is still running so that I sync with iPods.

It is running iTunes 11.  Is there a migration point at this point to get the music off the computer(without doing it manually)?

Answer (score 1):

Though Apple's monthly music subscription service offers similar functionality, I think the feature you're looking for is iTunes Match.

iTunes Match enables storing your music in the iTunes Cloud Library (as long as you don't have more than 100,000 songs to store in the cloud). It'll scan your library, match the songs to ones already in Apple's extensive library (to avoid uploading them), and upload the songs that it can't match. Once all your songs are uploaded or matched from your old iMac, you'll be able to pull them down onto other iOS and macOS devices — you'll either be able to stream them on demand or download them.

iTunes Match should be available in iTunes version 10 and later.

Here's some further info:

- [Apple – iTunes Match](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204146)
- [iMore – Apple Music vs iTunes Match](https://www.imore.com/apple-music-vs-itunes-match-whats-difference)

Comment: +1 It freezes so much now I'm fairly certain running a program like this won't work.  I have exported the xml list before and was hoping that could be used to import into Apple Music.